# Google Analytics - Display event statistic publicly

Tags: api, google-analytics, statistics

I'm tracking downloads with Google Analytics trackEvent.

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link', 'Download', 'Button']);" href="awesome.zip">Download now</a>
```

I would like to show the total downloads number publicly on my website. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, there is a way to show that on your website but it will require you to use the Google Analytics Core Reporting API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

I would provide a guide on how to do so but there are many ways and coding languages that you could use to do so and I am not sure what you are using!

You can find details of the Event Tracking Metrics/Dimensions here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/eventtracking

Comment: _I am not sure what you are using_ An example would be awesome! I can use PHP or JavaScript to display the stats.